# Where to ask for feedback on (Perl) CPAN modules?

Tags: discussion, scope, open-source, feedback

Say I've written a new Perl module on CPAN (or open-source module in any other language).  Is there an appropriate place, either on stackoverflow or any of the other stackexchange sites to ask for general community feedback?

The types of feedback that I would be interested in would be:

- general soundness of the idea
- any potential pitfalls / bugs related to the solution
- feature suggestions / revisions to existing features
- any other comments / feedback

Apologies in advance if this has been asked before, I searched but did not find anything I thought was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to ask for feedback about Perl modules is probably [comp.lang.perl.modules](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.modules/topics).