# Where do I ask for naming advice for a future Perl (CPAN) Module?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm currently developing a Perl Module, but haven't yet decided on its name. I have a few ideas and would like to know if these are rather good or bad names. I'm also open to completely new suggestions.

Where can I ask about such naming topics? It's a programming-related topic, but it's somehow also quite meta and has nothing to do with programming itself but rather with the community's view on Perl and CPAN.

This question is related to [Where to ask for feedback on (Perl) CPAN modules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70547/where-to-ask-for-feedback-on-perl-cpan-modules) but different in multiple directions:

- It's about names, not about code.
- It's about future modules, not about already uploaded ones.

The question IMHO also doesn't fit into [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff) because there are quite specific (although not that strict) rules about module naming on CPAN. So while parts of the question may look like a poll, I except answers to contain more constructive criticism (*You shouldn't use X because it could be confused with Y which already exists at Z*, *Module X uses namespace Y because of Z, so I suggest to use Y, too*, etc.) and less subjective views.

Comment: [ux.se] maybee?

Comment: Hrm. It's indeed also about where (in which module namespace) people would look for such a module, or with which terms they'd search for something like that on CPAN. But then again I dislike the "user" notion in there as it's mostly a developer's thing. Is there a "Developer's Experience" site? ;-)

Comment: Related: [How do I choose a package name for a custom Perl module that does not collide with builtin or CPAN packages names?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/658955). This is from early days of SO, so doesn't guarantee the question would be equally acceptable today. It does demonstrate a good approach: instead of localized/opinionated "what's the best name for my thing", it asks about naming practices that achieve a certain goal.

Comment: Good point. The question is indeed a different one, but the idea to ask that way is nice. I though fear my goals are rather generic: Function should be obvious from the name, easy to find via MetaCPAN/search.cpan.org, not too long, not to easy to confuse with other modules, etc.

Comment: that sounds like a [Naming Golf](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260752/two-posts-enter-one-post-leaves-merging-identical-questions-probably-inten#comment850128_260752)

Comment: Indeed. I though expect there's a) not enough of this kind of questions for a whole site on it's own, and b) there's still some knowledge of Perl and/or CPAN necessary to answer the question I have in mind. So while it probably would be fitting for a such a site, I'd expect more and better answers on StackOverflow despite I'm unsure if the question fits there. :-/

Comment: I really think this is a much better fit for Programmers than SO, since it's about a design/[naming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) issue. But since @gnat didn't suggest that, I have to wonder.

Comment: @NathanTuggy this would be a poor fit for Programmers, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat: Well, if those are reasons to keep it off Programmers, they're *certainly* reasons to keep it off SO.

Answer (score 3):

Post your code to [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com).  You can then ask as a side question: "By the way, what do you think of the name I chose for the module?"

Please be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  In particular, please do not ask a Code Review question with just stubs or placeholders.  There needs to be concrete, reviewable code.

You can post

- The entire code, if it fits in 30 kB
- A significant excerpt, enough to give a feel for what your module does and what problems might exist
- Optionally, a supplementary link to a third-party site such as GitHub

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion as it didn't come up in the comments yet. But there is not much more than a proof-of-concept script yet, which is surely not ready for a review. The only thing which is currently reviewable is the module name and the question about the module name currently holds me back to move the script into a proper module, i.e. holds me back to continue. I currently think this comment about Programmers.SE is currently the most fitting answer despite not being without doubt. But see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260 as posted by @gnat in another comment…

Answer (score 2):

The module-authors mailing list is a good place to ask for this kind of advice.

http://lists.perl.org/list/module-authors.html

Comment: The [tag:site-recommendations] tag indicates that the asker wants to know which Stack Exchange site the question should be asked on.

Comment: Indeed I wanted to know where in the StackExchange universe such a question would be most fitting. I though fear that is no appropriate place in the StackExchange universe yet. So I consider this anwer as the currently most satisfying answer nevertheless.